# How to i will solve ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17vEG.png)
I try to import Airfoil Data, but i got ModuleNotFoundError.
I have already done 'pip install airfoils' in control prompt and it was success.
I have also gave the parth in Enivorment variable setting.
Best regards
Karan Soni

I tried to import airfoil library, but i got Error.

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer. `pip` installed the airfoils package for one version of Python, but Jupyter is configured to use a different version.

Comment: If you don't want to sort out which version your Jupyter is using & don't mind potentially an extra install of that package on your system, you can run `%pip install airfoils` from inside the notebook where you want to use it. That magic command will insure it installs in the environment where the kernel is that backs your notebook. Restart your kernel after running the install and now `from airfoils import Airfoil` may work.

Comment: Hello John Gorden;  You are right. I solved my problem. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Hello Wayne; Thank you so much for your message. I will also try that one.